# Cannot stat the file path

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

Newbie here using Gitlab CI.

In my build stage, my binary is placed in /opt/binarydir/. I have declared this as an artifact path and in the release stage I am trying to copy the binary from this path but it says it cannot stat the file path, not found.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you provide the relevant gitlab-ci.yml snippets?

Comment: You are missing your code yes. Add it here.

Comment: Can you access the artifact of the build job via the website? In general you can only use files within the project workspace (`/build/<namepace>/<project>`) as artifacts, see [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#artifacts). Try moving the binary to the project workspace.

Comment: @sauerburger- Thanks, that was the solution.